# Adjusting photoshop interface size

Tags: photoshop

I have a high resolution mointor. Buttons and icons of Photoshop interface are too small for me. How can I make them bigger?

Comment: With the current information it's hard to help you. Could you please specify the version of your OS and Photoshop?

Comment: Apart from increasing font size I don't think you can.  You may get better help from Adobe forums

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the software interface on high-resolution monitors, and not using the tool for photography.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CS6 you can change color theme and font size in preferences->Interface.
If your version is older there is nothing you can do other than lowering your resolution.

Answer (score 2):

In theory changing the DPI settings in Windows will allow you to magnify what is displayed on the monitor - however it doesn't always work and some interfaces will look broken if you change the setting, but one can always try.

Comment: It does not affect icons, only rendered graphics such as fonts.

Comment: @Itai the DPI setting should affect all that is displayed on the monitor, irrespective of whether it is content or text -> that's the idea behind it, that those who need a scaled up image can have it.

Comment: The idea yes but not how it works unfortunately. I worked on computer graphics software for over 12 years and this has never worked. That is because a lot of user-interface such as all the Photoshop tool icons are bitmaps and simply get display one-pixel-for-one-pixel regardless of DPI settings. There is no easy way for the OS to change this because it has often no data on the intended DPI of the bitmap.

Comment: @Itai In this case the Bitmap should be stretched... A Bitmap is just a pixel for pixel image. The downside of this is, it would look bad.
Edit: OK, I just checked... Win7 & Photoshop CS4 - the menu text is bigger, the icons aren't...

Comment: They *should* be stretched but the OS does not know by *how much*. Most bitmap loaded in memory have no DPI data, so knowing the set DPI only gives half the info. If loading from a file like a JPEG or TIFF, there is a DPI field but alas it is often just a default value and not actual *intended* units. Yes, the menus and text are rendered since they are specified in points which has a meaning relative to DPI. Icons do not because they are just bitmaps. The OS only scales what is specified in a known unit and rendered.

Comment: Yes and a bitmap has a finite resolution - e.g. 10x10 pixels. So if I now want my DPI changed to 150% (100% / 125% / 150% are the options in Windows) it should just stretch the bitmap into 15x15 pixels. -> I really cannot see a problem there. The DPI setting is relative to some "normal" - I'm not sure if the OS knows what DPI my monitor has - it might, it might not. I think it works just on pixel values an icon is say 32x32 pixels large - that's it.